# Create a single object from an array of objects - JS/ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array:

```
[
    {"allocateProd1": "30.0000"}, 
    {"allocateProd2": "0"}, 
    {"allocateProd3": "0"},
    {"allocateProd4": "30"}
]
```

This array is dynamically generated as in the number of objects inside varies depending on data

I need an object:

```
{
    "allocateProd1": "30.0000", 
    "allocateProd2": "0", 
    "allocateProd3": "0", 
    "allocateProd4": "30"
}
```

Mostly going to use it in React. JS/ES6 solution will help

Comment: _"This array is dynamically generated as in the number of objects inside varies depending on data"_ Is the expected result for property names to be overwritten?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` + `spread syntax`.

```js
let arr = [
    {"allocateProd1": "30.0000"}, 
    {"allocateProd2": "0"}, 
    {"allocateProd3": "0"},
    {"allocateProd4": "30"}
];

let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, ...c}), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The alternative is using the function `Object.assign`

```js
let arr = [
    {"allocateProd1": "30.0000"}, 
    {"allocateProd2": "0"}, 
    {"allocateProd3": "0"},
    {"allocateProd4": "30"}
];

let result = arr.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Lovely. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Man, the more I learn about this language, the more neat things I can do with it. Creative answer!

Comment: @RonGilchrist yw!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness by taking the array and [spread `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the objects into [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an object as target. Voilà!

```js
var array = [{ allocateProd1: "30.0000"}, { allocateProd2: "0"}, { allocateProd3: "0"}, { allocateProd4: "30"}],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```